# Attribute 'src' in tag 'amp-mustache extension .js script' is set to the invalid value?

Tags: amp-html, amp-mustache

Currently trying to upgrade my AMP Mustache version from 0.1 to 0.2, as per the deprecation warning.  However, after doing so we began receiving the following error:

```
The attribute 'src' in tag 'amp-mustache extension .js script' is set to the invalid value 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js
```

Below is our exact include, please let us know if anything needs to be changed here:

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: see Github - discussed extensively there

Comment: The Github issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amp-mustache Version 0.2 is having some issue so validator is showing error. Now this is fixed.

[see reference](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17138)